# How to add customised ATAG variable in U-Boot and Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

I want to add customized `atag` variable in U-Boot and Linux kernel.
How can i achieve this?
Is there any procedure to add an `ATAG` variable in `U-Boot` and `Linux`?

Comment: You should probably look at using device trees. ATAGs are being deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this procedure ,

To achieve this goal, there're 2 parts need to be modified. One is the U-Boot, and the other one is the Linux kernel.

```
    1.    U-Boot changes required :

        A.     Make sure the  CONFIG_CMDLINE_TAG/CONFIG_SETUP_MEMORY_TAGS/CONFIG_INITRD_TAG are defined in you project definition header file ( u-boot/include/configs/am335x_evm.h ), and we  can add our own tag here, eg. CONFIG_CUSTOM_TAG.

        B.     Add the structure definition you wanna append w/ ATAG in u-boot/include/asm-arm/setup.h, eg.

            #define ATAG_CUSTOM 0x5441000a
            struct tag_custom{
            unsigned char mac_addr[6];
            };

        C.    Add the struct at the tail of "u"...

            struct tag {
                    struct tag_header hdr;
                    union {
                    struct tag_core         core;
                    struct tag_mem32        mem;
                    struct tag_videotext    videotext;
                    struct tag_ramdisk      ramdisk;
                    struct tag_initrd       initrd;
                    struct tag_serialnr     serialnr;
                    struct tag_revision     revision;
                    struct tag_videolfb     videolfb;
                    struct tag_cmdline      cmdline;

                    /*
                     * Acorn specific
                     */
                    struct tag_acorn        acorn;

                    /*
                     * DC21285 specific
                     */
                    struct tag_memclk       memclk;

                    /****** INFOTECH Custom TAG ********/

                   struct tag_custom custom;
                    } u;
                };

        D.    Add implementation code in lib_arm/bootm.c:

            static void setup_custom_tag(bd_t *bd);

            static void setup_custom_tag(bd_t *bd) {
                params->hdr.tag = ATAG_CUSTOM;
                   params->hdr.size = tag_size (tag_macaddr);
                params->u.custom.cmd =0;
                params = tag_next (params);
            }

        E.    Add "#ifdef CONFIG_CUSTOM_TAG / #endif" at every place you change the code.

        F.    Done of U-Boot modification.

2. Linux Changes required:

        A.    Add parse tag code in linux/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c:

            int cmd;
            static int __init parse_tag_custom(const struct tag *tag){
                    printk("u.custom.cmd=%d\n",tag->u.custom.cmd);
                return 0;
            }

            __tagtable(ATAG_MACADDR, parse_tag_custom);

        B. Add the structure declaration as U-Boot did in linux/include/asm-arm/setup.h:

            #define ATAG_MACADDR 0x5441000a
            struct tag_custom {
                int cmd;
            };

        C. Add the struct at the tail of "u"...

            struct tag {
                struct tag_header hdr;
               union {
                    struct tag_core         core;
                 struct tag_mem32        mem;
                struct tag_videotext    videotext;
                struct tag_ramdisk      ramdisk;
                struct tag_initrd       initrd;
                struct tag_serialnr     serialnr;
                struct tag_revision     revision;
                struct tag_videolfb     videolfb;
                struct tag_cmdline      cmdline;

                /*
                 * Acorn specific
                 */
                struct tag_acorn        acorn;

                /*
                 * DC21285 specific
                 */
                struct tag_memclk       memclk;

                /* Add Infotech custom tag */

                struct tag_custom      custom;
                } u;
            };

        D. Done w/ Kernel parts.
```

Answer (score 6):

The latest Linux kernel is attempting to obsolete **ATAGS** with *device trees*.  However, the [setup.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/setup.h) file defines the different **ATAG** values and structures.  To parse these, you need to add them with something like,

```
static int __init parse_tag_custom(const struct tag *tag)
{
    if (tag->hdr.size > CUSTOM_SIZE) {
         /* Use, storing or acting on passed values */ 
         tag->u.custom;
    }
    return 0;
}

__tagtable(ATAG_CUSTOM, parse_tag_custom);
```

as found in [atags_parse.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/atags_parse.c).   Of course, you need to add these to the values in *setup.h*.

*u-boot* is probably less defined as for the most part, it passes arguments via the kernel command line as this is not **ARM** specific.  A *command argument* or *device trees* is probably the preferred method.  If you gave an example of what type of configuration you need, someone could probably give better guidance.

Comment: For reference: [Linux ARM boot docs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/arm/Booting), explaining ATAGS, etc.

Comment: Moved [booting.rst](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arch/arm/booting.rst)

Answer (score 5):

1. U-Boot changes required :

   ```
   A.     Make sure the  CONFIG_CMDLINE_TAG/CONFIG_SETUP_MEMORY_TAGS/CONFIG_INITRD_TAG are defined in you project definition header file ( u-boot/include/configs/am335x_evm.h ), and we  can add our own tag here, eg. CONFIG_CUSTOM_TAG.

   B.     Add the structure definition you wanna append w/ ATAG in u-boot/include/asm-arm/setup.h, eg.

       #define ATAG_CUSTOM 0x5441000a
       struct tag_custom{
       unsigned char mac_addr[6];
       };

   C.    Add the struct at the tail of "u"...

       struct tag {
               struct tag_header hdr;
               union {
               struct tag_core         core;
               struct tag_mem32        mem;
               struct tag_videotext    videotext;
               struct tag_ramdisk      ramdisk;
               struct tag_initrd       initrd;
               struct tag_serialnr     serialnr;
               struct tag_revision     revision;
               struct tag_videolfb     videolfb;
               struct tag_cmdline      cmdline;

               /*
                * Acorn specific
                */
               struct tag_acorn        acorn;

               /*
                * DC21285 specific
                */
               struct tag_memclk       memclk;

               /****** INFOTECH Custom TAG ********/

              struct tag_custom custom;
               } u;
           };

   D.    Add implementation code in lib_arm/bootm.c:

       static void setup_custom_tag(bd_t *bd);

       static void setup_custom_tag(bd_t *bd) {
           params->hdr.tag = ATAG_CUSTOM;
              params->hdr.size = tag_size (tag_macaddr);
           params->u.custom.cmd =0;
           params = tag_next (params);
       }

   E.    Add "#ifdef CONFIG_CUSTOM_TAG / #endif" at every place you change the code.

   F.    Done of U-Boot modification.
   ```

   1. Linux Changes required:

      A.    Add parse tag code in linux/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c:

      ```
      int cmd;
      static int __init parse_tag_custom(const struct tag *tag){
              printk("u.custom.cmd=%d\n",tag->u.custom.cmd);
          return 0;
      }

      __tagtable(ATAG_MACADDR, parse_tag_custom);
      ```

      B. Add the structure declaration as U-Boot did in linux/include/asm-arm/setup.h:

      ```
      #define ATAG_MACADDR 0x5441000a
      struct tag_custom {
          int cmd;
      };
      ```

      C. Add the struct at the tail of "u"...

      ```
      struct tag {
          struct tag_header hdr;
         union {
              struct tag_core         core;
           struct tag_mem32        mem;
          struct tag_videotext    videotext;
          struct tag_ramdisk      ramdisk;
          struct tag_initrd       initrd;
          struct tag_serialnr     serialnr;
          struct tag_revision     revision;
          struct tag_videolfb     videolfb;
          struct tag_cmdline      cmdline;

          /*
           * Acorn specific
           */
          struct tag_acorn        acorn;

          /*
           * DC21285 specific
           */
          struct tag_memclk       memclk;

          /* Add Infotech custom tag */

          struct tag_custom      custom;
          } u;
      };
      ```

      D. Done w/ Kernel parts.