# What are ATAGs for a device that uses Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, boot

I am trying to understand how a kernel boots. I am currently trying to port a new kernel to hTC Incredible S VIVO (s710e) device, but I cannot get it to boot. So, I looked into the device's original kernel, and looked through some documentation, and found out that the device uses ATAGs. Now, I have several questions that I cannot find a clear answer for:

- What are ATAGs?
- What are they used for?
- How does the kernel boot using ATAGs?
- Do ATAGs play a vital role in booting a kernel?

Comment: [Custom ATAGS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661550/how-to-add-customised-atag-variable-in-u-boot-and-linux-kernel), [Why a boot loader in Embedded/ARM device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548004/why-do-we-need-a-bootloader-in-an-embedded-device), [ARM ATAGS vs Device Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014920/arm-linux-atags-vs-device-tree)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ATAGS are ARM tags. They are used to carry information such as memory size from boot code to kernel. Some references (which in turn lead to other references): [booting standards,](https://superuser.com/questions/569655/are-there-any-booting-standards-for-arm-based-computers) [customized ATAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661550/how-to-add-customised-atag-variable-in-u-boot-and-linux-kernel/).

This reference [arm/Booting](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/arm/Booting) explains theory, but does not much tell a user what to do.

On my target I use the following in my U-Boot config: CONFIG_CMDLINE_TAG, CONFIG_SETUP_MEMORY_TAGS, and these in my kernel config: CONFIG_ATAGS=y, CONFIG_USE_OF is not set. Not sure if that is sufficient for you but it gives you clues to search on, good luck.

Comment: Thank You very much. May I please see your kernel source code?

Comment: arm/Booting link = "Path not found" :-(

Answer (score 0):

ATAGS are not only arm-related, at all. Look into other archs head.S. They are special parameters to be passed to the kernel through some registers and  pointers.